# Basic FireBase Word Change

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am making a simple app that I need to use fire base so I can update a text everyday. Just think of it as a daily quote app that I manually change everyday on fire base so I don't need to republish every time I change the quote. I have found tuturiols on how to connect Fire Base with my Android Studio Project but I have not been able to find any on having the Text updatable on Fire Base. If anyone can help or redirect me to such a tutorial I would really like that. Thank you.

Comment: using firebase database, listen for text change and update textfield in Android

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking as moving data from the Firebase server to the app is a core function of Firebase and covered in the [Getting Started Guides](https://firebase.google.com/docs/guides/). Can you clarify what you are asking?